# How to use svn command line on windows xp?

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows XP. I use GUI for operations like `svn commit` and `svn update`.

How can I start command line for SVN operations ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the svn  command line binaries from [here](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html). Tortoise doesn't offer a stand-alone `svn.exe`, I figure it has the libraries embedded in a DLL.

Comment: Make sure the binaries you get match the ones that TortoiseSVN uses.  Generally 1.5.x binaries won't work with a 1.6.x work copy and other great combinations and cause even more fun issues.  As long as both Tortoise and svn.exe are a the same major version you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Subversion command-line tools (e.g. `svn.exe`) are now available as a part of the [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) installer. You can choose whether to install them or not on the third page of TortoiseSVN installer.